# Strange outputs for a moving platform in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First off, sorry it this isn't written very well, I've spend hours debugging this and I'm very stressed. I'm trying to make a moving platform in unity that can move between way-points, I don't want to have to have tons of gameobjects in the world taking up valuable processing power though so I'm trying to use something I can just add to the script through the editor.

The only problem is that it seems to be doing this at an incredible speed:
[image]
Black = The Camera View, Blue = The platform and where it should be going based on waypoints, Red = What it is currently doing.

I've spend hours trying to find a fix but I have no idea why it's doing this.

My Script on the Platform:

```
public Vector3[] localWaypoints;
    Vector3[] globalWaypoints;

    public float speed;
    public bool cyclic;
    public float waitTime;
    [Range(0, 2)]
    public float easeAmount;

    int fromWaypointIndex;
    float percentBetweenWaypoints;
    float nextMoveTime;

    void Start()
    {

        globalWaypoints = new Vector3[localWaypoints.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < localWaypoints.Length; i++)
        {
            globalWaypoints[i] = localWaypoints[i] + transform.position;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {


        Vector3 velocity = CalculatePlatformMovement();
        transform.Translate(velocity);
    }

    float Ease(float x)
    {
        float a = easeAmount + 1;
        return Mathf.Pow(x, a) / (Mathf.Pow(x, a) + Mathf.Pow(1 - x, a));
    }

    Vector3 CalculatePlatformMovement()
    {

        if (Time.time < nextMoveTime)
        {
            return Vector3.zero;
        }

        fromWaypointIndex %= globalWaypoints.Length;
        int toWaypointIndex = (fromWaypointIndex + 1) % globalWaypoints.Length;
        float distanceBetweenWaypoints = Vector3.Distance(globalWaypoints[fromWaypointIndex], globalWaypoints[toWaypointIndex]);
        percentBetweenWaypoints += Time.deltaTime * speed / distanceBetweenWaypoints;
        percentBetweenWaypoints = Mathf.Clamp01(percentBetweenWaypoints);
        float easedPercentBetweenWaypoints = Ease(percentBetweenWaypoints);

        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Lerp(globalWaypoints[fromWaypointIndex], globalWaypoints[toWaypointIndex], easedPercentBetweenWaypoints);

        if (percentBetweenWaypoints >= 1)
        {
            percentBetweenWaypoints = 0;
            fromWaypointIndex++;

            if (!cyclic)
            {
                if (fromWaypointIndex >= globalWaypoints.Length - 1)
                {
                    fromWaypointIndex = 0;
                    System.Array.Reverse(globalWaypoints);
                }
            }
            nextMoveTime = Time.time + waitTime;
        }

        return newPos - transform.position;
    }


    struct PassengerMovement
    {
        public Transform transform;
        public Vector3 velocity;
        public bool standingOnPlatform;
        public bool moveBeforePlatform;

        public PassengerMovement(Transform _transform, Vector3 _velocity, bool _standingOnPlatform, bool _moveBeforePlatform)
        {
            transform = _transform;
            velocity = _velocity;
            standingOnPlatform = _standingOnPlatform;
            moveBeforePlatform = _moveBeforePlatform;
        }
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (localWaypoints != null)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            float size = .3f;

            for (int i = 0; i < localWaypoints.Length; i++)
            {
                Vector3 globalWaypointPos = (Application.isPlaying) ? globalWaypoints[i] : localWaypoints[i] + transform.position;
                Gizmos.DrawLine(globalWaypointPos - Vector3.up * size, globalWaypointPos + Vector3.up * size);
                Gizmos.DrawLine(globalWaypointPos - Vector3.left * size, globalWaypointPos + Vector3.left * size);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Upon further testing I found that if the first object in my localWaypoint array is set to 0,0,0 and my 2nd object is set to 1,0,0 then the platform will spiral to the right, making sure to hit the waypoints as it's spiraling, and then spiraling out into nowhere like in the image above. But if I set my first object to 0,0,0 and my second object to -1,0,0 then the object will act the same way as before, but will spiral to the left as displayed in this image. (The second image has also bee updated to display how the platfrom makes sure to hit both waypoints before is spirals out into nowhere).

[image]

I've also noticed that if I set both waypoints to 0,0,0 then the platform stays still, these 2 things prove that it has somthing to do with the way the waypoints are being handled and not some other script or parent object interfering.

Comment: Your code appears to work with a simple dataset.  What is the dataset that you are using for the waypoints?

Comment: Is there another script running somewhere that could influence the position of your platform?

Comment: I wonder if your platform is stored within an empty game object that didn't have its transform reset before making the platform a child object? If this is the case, you may want to remove all child objects from the empty and reset the transform then put the children back. On Run, children take the parents transform position and causes strange things like this to happen.

Comment: Checkout docs for translate.

Comment: @Topher I don't have any other scripts tied to it that would be affecting it otherwise, I assume when you say dataset you mean the where my waypoints are located, I have 2 right now, element0 is located at 0,0,0 and element1 is loacted at 1,0,0.

Comment: @AntonioTorro The Platform is not a child of anything, so I don't see what else could be affecting it.

Comment: @user14492 That's not helpful, I have a pretty good understanding how how transform.translate works, if you see a specific flaw please speak up though.

Comment: **To those who have already commented and are doing a follow up:** I have done some more testing and found an oddity, read the update I made to the original post above before commenting again, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the updated numbers ([0,0,0], [1,0,0]) works in my test app.   However, if I put a rotation on the object's Y axis, then I see behavior like you are seeing.  In Update, if you change:

```
transform.Translate(velocity);
```

to

```
transform.Translate(velocity, Space.World);
```

You should see your desired behavior.  Note that "transform.Translate(velocity)" is the same as "transform.Translate(velocity, Space.Self)".  Your translation is being rotated.

If you are curious, take a look at this for more information on how the values in the transform are applied:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138358/what-is-the-transformation-order-when-using-the-transform-class

Comment: That works flawlessly! Thank you very much, and thank you for providing resources to learn about how the change affected  it!